# SQLite Insert Query Multiple Database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I wrote the following code to insert some records into table from the table of another database.
But I'm unable to, even after executing a sql statement it shows that there are no records in the table.

```
public int copy_to_all_source_table(String dbpath,String backpath)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //Opening App database(i.e. dbpath) and attaching it as "OLD" 
    db1.openDatabase(dbpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    String attach_old="ATTACH '"+ dbpath +"' AS OLD";
    db1.execSQL(attach_old);

    //Opening New File which is Student.db(i.e. dbpath) and attaching it as "NEW"        
    db1.openDatabase(backpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    String attach_new="ATTACH '"+ backpath +"' AS NEW";
    db1.execSQL(attach_new);

    // Getting count of records in table of "NEW" 
    String new_query =" SELECT * FROM 'NEW'.'"+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"'";
    Cursor new_data = db1.rawQuery(new_query, null);          
    Integer new_count= new_data.getCount();


    //INSERTING ALL RECORDS FROM TABLE OF NEW TO TABLE OF OLD
    String insert_query ="INSERT INTO 'OLD'.'"+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"' SELECT * FROM 'NEW'.'"+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"'";
    Cursor success_insert = db1.rawQuery(insert_query, null);

    // Getting count of records in table of "NEW"
    String after_insert_old_query =" SELECT * FROM 'OLD'.'"+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"'";
    Cursor old_data = db1.rawQuery(after_insert_old_query, null);             
    Integer old_count= old_data.getCount();
}
```

**RESULT:**

```
new_count = 11
old_count = 0
```

So, no record has been inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `rawQuery()` to execute an INSERT **command**. Which **will never work**.
Use `execSQL()`, instead

Moreover, the last comment is misleading, because it says you want the count from the **NEW** table, but you are counting from the **OLD** one.

And, please, get rid of the **string delimiter characters** (**'**).
I.e.:

this

```
String new_query =" SELECT * FROM 'NEW'.'"+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"'";
```

should be

```
String new_query = "SELECT * FROM NEW." +  TABLE_CONTACTS;
```